# High-probability bound on # of times empirical mean fails to concentrate

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, concentration-of-measure

### Previous result

The book "Bandit Algorithms" by Lattimore and Szepesvári includes the following result (Lemma 8.2, page 98), which I have simplified and paraphrased for my use case:

> Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be a sequence of independent $1$-subgaussian random variables
> and $\epsilon > 0$.
> Denote the empirical mean of the $X_s$ by
> $$\hat \mu_t = \frac 1 t \sum_{s=1}^t X_s$$
> and the $\epsilon$-overestimate count by
> $$ \kappa_n = \sum_{t=1}^n \mathbb{I} \left\{ \hat \mu_t \geq \epsilon \right\}, $$
> where $\mathbb{I}(\cdot)$ denotes an indicator variable. Then
> $$ \mathbb{E}[\kappa_n] \leq \frac{2}{\epsilon^2}.$$

### Desired variant

I need to control the probability of large $\kappa_n$ instead of $\kappa_n$'s expected value.
In other words, I need a result like:

Let $0 < \delta < 1$ be a confidence level.
There is a function $f$ such that
$$
    \Pr \left\{ \kappa_n \geq f \left( \frac 1 \epsilon, \frac 1 \delta, n \right) \right\} \leq \delta.
$$
Ideally $f$ would *not* depend on $n$, but I am not sure if that's possible.

### Proof efforts

The expected-value version from Lattimore and Szepesvári depends heavily on linearity of expectation: The first step is that

$$
   \mathbb{E}[\kappa_n] = \sum_{t=1}^n \Pr \left\{ \hat \mu_t \geq \epsilon \right\},
$$

which immediately avoids dealing with the fact that the tail events
$\hat \mu_t \geq \epsilon$  and
$\hat \mu_{t+1} \geq \epsilon$  are not independent.
This allows them to apply a Chernoff/Hoeffding bound to each tail event and sum them up.
But for my desired result, I have not been able to find a trick that allows me to break up the dependence like that.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: There's always Markov's inequality. Another option is to see that $\mathbf{1}\{\hat\mu_t \ge \varepsilon\} \le \hat\mu_t/\varepsilon,$ from which you should be able to argue that $\kappa_n$ is subGaussian (although this will probably have some $n$ dependence in the tail bounds).